# In Word, how can I sort/rank paragraphs by the order of a specific line?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I reorder while preserving each para(graph)'s wholeness? 
Home > Sort disorders  them.

[image]

Comment: Is the character after the 2 (and 3 and 1) a hard line end, or what? If I use that and use a "normal" paragraph mark after the B, A, C then the sort works OK here.

Comment: @bibadia Sorry, but what's a `hard line end`? I'm a tech novice. I just meant 2 to mark the start of a sentence, according to which I want the paras ordered properly by MS Word.

Comment: You have B on a separate line from 2. So what is between the 2 and the B? You can see "non-display" characters in Word 2013 by clicking the "pilcrow" button at the top right of the Paragraph sectin of the Home tab - not sure you will be able to see this but it looks like this: ¶ If you then see such a sign after the "2", it means that your "2" and "B" are in separate paragraphs.

Comment: Further to bibadia's help, here is what it should look like: http://prntscr.com/57f031

Comment: @bibadia I confirm that after ensuring that the pilcrow sign has been selected, my input matches Adam's screenshot exactly. I intend 2 and B to form 1 para, but on 2 different lines. So there's nothing between 2 and B?

Comment: Adam's screenshot shows exactly what I started with, too. i.e. it works OK here. At the moment I can't see a reason why our copies of Word would behave differently, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the procedure below.

Starting document contains:

[image]

**1. Convert every three paragraphs to one paragraph**

Position to the beginning of the document and type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for *Replace*.

In the dialog, check "Use wildcards" and set:

Find what: `(*)^13(*)^13(*)^13`
Replace with: `\1#\2#\3^13`

Explanation:

`^13` : end-of-paragraph
`(*)` : any string, marked as a group
`#` : a random strange character that does not occur in the text
`\n` : group number n

Pressing *Replace All* gives the following result:

[image]

**2. Sort the lines by the most suitable sort order**

This gives:

[image]

**3. Break up the lines**

Position to the beginning of the document and type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for *Replace*.

In the dialog, check "Use wildcards" and set:

Find what: `(*)#(*)#(*)^13`
Replace with: `\1^13\2^13\3^13`

Pressing *Replace All* gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the delay. I forgot to remind myself in Outlook of this bounty!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a table, but have placed all the data in a single row, separated in 3 columms, so the each word isnt "connected" to the next one in the same columm.
If you want to avoid having borders between the data, you can disable these in the design tab, and then separate the data in different rows created from the layout tab

That should allow you to then order the data correctly

EDIT: Extra note, when sorting, dont forget to mark the "My List: Has header rows" option just above the Options button, or the headers will also get sorted and probably end up somewhere random in your table

Answer (score 0):

I think **`SHIFT+ENTER`** is what you're looking for. Please check out the sample images below.

I've taken the content from Juanjo's answer for testing.

**Initial Paragraph:** before sorting 
 
[image: Word - Sort Paragraph-1]

The Enter symbol in the above image indicates that the next line is in the same paragraph

**After Sorting:** 
 
[image: Word - Sort Paragraph-2]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify how you sorted? To what did you apply SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: Hitting Enter directly will create a new paragraph, so the first letter you enter after hitting enter will be considered for sorting. But the text you enter after Shift-Enter won't be considered as a new paragraph. That's how you can trick Word how to sort.