# How can I alphabetize text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Please see the GIF below. As you can see, the Sort tool didn't alphabetize the text.

1. The correct order ought be A (Z), B (X), C (Y).
2. How can I alphabetize by the text in brackets? Then the order's B (X), C (Y), A (Z).
3. How can I alphabetize by integers? For the second line, order's 1 (B), 2 (C), 3 (A).

[image]

Comment: What you are hoping for is not possible, because neither text is a "one level bulleted or numbered list". Ref: [docs](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sort-a-list-alphabetically-1f938032-2158-4bf3-be0d-4536375055c6)

Comment: What if you do find and replace to put each on separate paragraph before your sort.  So find comma space and replace with ^p for paragraph.  Then do the sort.  Then you can put back to list with commas but finding ^p and replacing with comma space.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for cannot be done. [Reference](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sort-a-list-alphabetically-1f938032-2158-4bf3-be0d-4536375055c6)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/894198)

Comment: You may well be correct, at least using native features.  However, "Shortly put,..." is really the TLDR on an actual answer that explains why.  More information than this has already been presented in a comment, so this would even be an inferior comment.  Can you expand this into an answer?

Comment: @RajeshS Please note that while this answer might benefit from an explanation and/or information as fixer1234 notes; broadly speaking, **an answer which says something is not possible is generally a valid answer**.

Comment: @bertieb, thanks for observation,, I picked one of the best suitable while reviewing the post,, honestly I was expecting more on the OP's issue by the Author !!

Comment: @RajeshS I don't believe this answer merits deletion- it could be expanded with an explanation and reference, but it's still an answer.

Comment: Oh. I put a reference to prove my answer.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin, that doesn't prove your answer that ti can't be done, it just shows how to do a basic sort using the built-in tools.  Obviously, a more sophisticated approach would be required.  Just saying it can't be done means it is impossible by any means.  Have you seen [In Word, how can I sort/rank paragraphs by the order of a specific line?](https://superuser.com/q/840751/364367)?

Comment: @bertieb, saying something can't be done can potentially be a valid answer.  But without any context or explanation, that, alone, isn't useful.  What does "can't" mean? (absolutely impossible in any way under any circumstances? impossible using native tools? impossible in some cases, but maybe not the OP's situation? the poster just isn't familiar with a solution? it's baseless BS trolling?)  There's no way to assess what the claim means, what limitations might be implied, whether it's actually correct and supported by an authoritative source, etc.